# How to create directory on FirefoxOS apps in FirefoxOS device?

Tags: firefox-os

I my application to create a directory on a FirefoxOS device.

Anyone knows how to do that?

[Addition] how to create file

1. [SDCard] = navigator.getDeviceStorage( 'sdcard' )
2. [Blob Object] = new Blob()
3. [SDCard].addNamed( [Blob Object], fileName )

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the full path relative to the device storage. Directories are automatically created for you when you save a file with `addNamed`. Let say want to save a file named `test.txt` in the folder `examples` of the sdcard.

Then you'll have to save the blob with the name `examples/test.txt`.

```
var sdcard = navigator.getDeviceStorage("sdcard");
var file   = new Blob(["This is a text file."], {type: "text/plain"});
var request = sdcard.addNamed(file, "examples/test.txt");

request.onsuccess = function () {
  var name = this.result.name;
  console.log('File "' + name + '" successfully wrote on the sdcard storage area');
}

request.onerror = function () {
  console.warn('Unable to write the file: ' + this.error);
}
```

Here read this from the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DeviceStorage/addNamed):

> Note: Repository in a storage area is implicit; it's not possible to
>   explicitly create an empty repository. If you want to use a repository
>   structure you have to make it part of the name of the file to store.
>   So if you want to store the file bar inside the foo repository, you
>   have to provide the complete path name of the file: addNamed(blob,
>   "foo/bar").
>
> As files are added in a given restricted storage area, for security
>   reasons, a file path name cannot start with "/" nor "../" (and "./" is
>   pointless).